# Nullhomotopy special case.

Tags: algebraic-topology

If we have a $k$-dim proper smooth submanifold $N \varsubsetneq M$ and suppose we have the retraction map $r|_N:M→N$. Furthermore, we impose the condition that $N \cong S^n \times S^n$ (diffeomorphism).

How would one show $i : N \hookrightarrow M$ is not nullhomotopic?

I think the best way is to argue by contradiction (by assuming such a homotopy exists). I think the contradiction lies in the assumed diffeomorphism, which suggests I look at the retraction  $r|_N:M→N$, because this looks awfully like the diffeomorphism in question…

If someone could give me some ideas, it would be great.

Comment: Have you heard about homology?

Comment: @Dan, yes, but why is that helpful here…?

Comment: oh yes it is. Notice that such retractions give always rise to injections if you apply a covariant functor the map they retract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that homology is a covariant functor, in particular the existence of a retraction implies the inclusion to be *injective*! (the reason is: $id=id_*=(ri)_*=r_*i_*$)

But we know that $N$ has non trivial homology in higher dimensions. Hence, by injectivity, $i_*$ has non trivial image in higher dimensions. Hence the inclusion $i$ is not nullhomotopic (such maps factor up to homotopy through a point, but homology is a homotopy functor).

Comment: I wish i had said "no"...

Comment: But you don't need very much about homology to understand this answer. Read it carefully and you will maybe still get an idea, why $i$ is not nullhomotopic.

Comment: Right now I am trying to understand what the induced homemorphism here means…I am very new to this subject so I am slow. (reading a book right now to understand lol)

Comment: I got a silly question (I think I understand your first sentence lol), what is meant by "nontrivial homology"? What is the trivial homology?

Comment: I should have maybe said "non trivial homology groups", since we have a sequence of groups. A group is considered trivial if it is isomorphic to the trivial group 0. You get this statement by observing that $H_n(S^n)$ is non trivial, and the inclusion of $S^n$ into $S^n\times S^n$ induces a non trivial map on homology by the same argument as in my answer.